# Identity with moore penrose inverse

Tags: numerical-methods, pseudoinverse

I consider $ A\in \mathbb{K}^{m,n} $ with SVD
$$ A=U\cdot \Sigma \cdot \overline{V}^T $$
with $ U\in \mathcal{O}(m), V\in \mathcal{O}(n) $ orhtogonal and $ \Sigma \in \mathbb{K}^{m,n} $.

Then

$ i)\quad \mathcal{N} \left (A^{\dagger} \right)=\mathcal{N} \left (\overline{A}^T \right)\\ ii)\quad \mathcal{R} \left (A^{\dagger} \right)=\mathcal{R} \left (\overline{A}^T \right) $

At first I want to show i):

$ \overline{A}^T=V\cdot \Sigma^T \cdot \overline{U}^T\\ A^\dagger=V\cdot \Sigma^{-1}\cdot \overline{U}^T $

Let $ x\in \mathcal{N} \left (A^{\dagger} \right) \Leftrightarrow A^\dagger\cdot x=V\cdot \Sigma^{-1}\cdot \overline{U}^T\cdot x=0$ But from here I get stuck to show $ \overline{A}^T\cdot x=0 $.